# Entity Framework code first relationships and navigation property?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

i have the following classes

```
public class Subject{
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public String SubjectName { get; set; }
        public String SubjectCategory { get; set; }
    }

public class QuestionDescriptor {
        public int QuestionDescriptorId { get; set; }        
        public String QuestionText { get; set; }
        public String Answer { get; set; } 
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    }
```

i have configured it using the following code ,i want that a Subject can have many QuestionDescriptors

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionDescriptor>()
                .HasRequired(qd => qd.Subject)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(qd => qd.SubjectId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Now i have the following question

1. have i done it correctly ?
2. do i need a navigation property in the Subject class?
3. what happems if i do this

   ```
   public class Subject {
           public int SubjectId { get; set; }
           public String SubjectName { get; set; }
           public String SubjectCategory { get; set; }
           public int QuestionDescriptorId {get;set;}
           public virtual QuestionDescriptor {get;set;} 
       }
   ```
4. if i do the above what changes do i need in the configuration and why?
5. if i want all the questions belonging to a particular subject then i can get them by querying the QuestionDescriptor ,why then do i need a bi-directional property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) have i done it correctly ?

Yes.

> 2) do i need a navigation property in the Subject class?

No. You don't need it. It can be helpful for certain queries but it is not required.

> 3) what happems if i do this ...

That's another relationship. It would represent a one-to-one relationship. But because you want a one-to-many relationship you must have a navigation *collection* on your entity:

```
public class Subject {
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public String SubjectName { get; set; }
    public String SubjectCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionDescriptor> Descriptors {get;set;} 
}
```

> 4) if i do the above what changes do i need in the configuration and
>   why?

For the change above you can leave you mapping configuration as it is - with the only exception that you now must specify the collection as the other side of the relationship. Instead of `.WithMany()` you use

```
.WithMany(s => s.Descriptors)
```

> 5) if i want all the questions belonging to a particular subject then
>   i can get them by querying the QuestionDescriptor ,why then do i need
>   a bi-directional property ?

You don't need it.

Comment: In the 3 question if i have just a navigation property ,doesn't that change my table structure in the database ?

Comment: @ashutoshraina: In your example in the question with `public virtual QuestionDescriptor`, yes, it would change the table structure because it's a one-to-one relationship. In my example with `public virtual ICollection<QuestionDescriptor> Descriptors` it doesn't change the database because the relationship is still the same (one-to-many).

Comment: yes, you are right.i tried it out and there was no change in the database structure and it made my querying straightforward.Many thanks for the help.