# Code First and data loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

I should make a choice between EF code first or model first.

I'm not sure what is the best solution for development efficiency and simplest solution for IoC framework integration.

I have tried to start with code first but I could not make the navigation properties to be used as IQueryable. When I declare navigation properties I use ICollection like:

```
public class Invoice {
...
   public ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
...
}
```

and

```
public class LineItem {
...
   public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
...
}
```

When I load Invoice, my LineItems collection is empty because of lazy load.

But when I load this property from database will I load all LineItems of this Invoice from database before I could use this Collection as IQueryable?

My idea is to use IQueryable to make database loading as minimal as possible to increase performance.

What I'm doing wrong? What is the best practice?

When I use Database first I can use my navigation properties as IQueryable out of the box without writing any proxy classes or wrappers.

Thank you

Comment: "my navigation properties as IQueryable" - that's not always a plus.

Comment: Why? I can apply a query to my collection property to build SQL query before database will be disturbed

Comment: Looks like lazyloading is doing What you want, delay the actual query to the database until you actually access the record/entity. But in some cases, you will have to do eagerloading or turn off lazyloading/proxy, which will be different story though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make all of your entity properties virtual. This allows EF to generate a proxy class for your entity, such that you can query over it.

```
public class Invoice {
     public virtual ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I enabled lazy loading this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; and set my nav. properties as virtual. But it not affects to loading of navigation properties. Invoice LineItems are loading with the Invoice. They are not null by default.

Comment: Lazyloading is on by default for EF 4.1. And if you have your LineItems `virtual`, I suspect you need look at elsewhere for the problem. This http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx, and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619227/entity-framework-code-first-relationships-and-navigation-property should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You **need** `Virtual` Keyword to make Lazyloading working.